# Line plot x axis using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, line

result

```
   year  Month  Min_days    Avg_days    Median_days     Count
    2015   1          9        12.56666666          10         4
    2015   2          10       13.67678788          9          3    
   ........................................................
    2016   12       12       15.7889990           19          2
    and so on...
```

I wish to create a line plot plotting min_days, avg_days, median_days, count according to month and year say. how can I do that

Codes tried till now

```
axes = result.plot.line(subplots=True)
type(axes)
```

This works great but I m also getting subplots of year and month. I want year and month to be on x axis

**Code2 tried:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
result.groupby('Year').plot(x='Year', y='Median_days', ax=ax, legend=False)
```

The issue with this code is it groupbys only year. I need month too (Jan 2015, Feb 2015 and so on). Also another issue is This gives me a single subplot for Median. How to add subplots for mean, min etc

**Edit:**
P.S. Also if someone can answer in case month int is replaced with month names (Jan, Feb etc. it would be great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to first create a year-month column:

```
result["year-month"] = pd.to_datetime(
    result.year.astype(str) + "-" + result.Month.astype(str)
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for col in ["Min_days", "Avg_days", "Median_days", "Count"]:
    ax.plot(result["year-month"], result[col], label=col)
ax.legend(loc="best")
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=30)
```

With the limited data you've given us, you'll get:
[image]

Comment: Hi sorry, the column is month name not month . Also the Year and Month name are indices not column names since result is a groupby output. So error I am getting is Keyword error: Year

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor then do `.reset_index()` first, and change `.month` to `['Month Name']`

Comment: where should i do reset index ? Do you mean like this : result = result.reset_index()?

Comment: File "<ipython-input-94-9c6c8955ef21>", line 7
    result.Year.astype(str) + "-" + result.['Month Name'].astype(str)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: remove the `.` between `result` and `[`

Comment: No error now but  I am getting only year names now also, nothing like Jan 2015, Feb 2015 and so on'....I am getting 2015, 2016, 2017 and so on.........

Comment: Please don't edit questions after they have received answers so that the question no longer reflects the question - originally, you had numbers in your `month` column

Comment: Edited the question now to reflect original'

Comment: Last thing even with your solution of month as ints, the x axis still refelcts 2015, 2016 and so on and not 2015-01 like you have depicted. No idea why thats happening

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor sorry about that - I'll take another look at this in a couple of hours :)

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor just tried again, and can't reproduce your error. What versions of matplotlib and pandas are you using? Perhaps try upgrading: `pip install --upgrade matplotlib pandas`